# DHCP Server with 2 nics

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, dhcp, nat

I have windows 2008 r2 x64 enterprise server with a domain.

That server has 2 NIC

nic1 which is connected to a router
nic2 - here i need 
1) run dhcp for private LAN 
2) forward internet connection from nic1
3) using NAT

[image: http://m73i.imgup.net/2015-11-043f07.png]

I can't connect the router to my network because it's act as DHCP server and I don't have access on it to disable this option.

if you have an idea, solution or even a tutorial I would be grateful.
Best regards

Comment: Change the router, period. You are making a error by multihoming the server because of that particular problem. (by the way, I downvoted because of the point I told)

Comment: I can't change the router because it's given by the Internet Access provider to our institution. so  I don't have a choice so if you have a solution i would be grateful !
and by the way thanks for your vote !!!!

Comment: Why are you not allowed to disable DHCP on the router?

Comment: because it's predefined by the service provider
Cordially

Comment: Call them. I work for an isp, they can easilly remove that. AS, you know your setup will be multihoming AND double nat. Thus you will have problem to do anything complex. You cant even do a site to site vpn

Answer (score 1):

Well, multi-homing a DC (I assume that's what you mean by 'with a domain') is **not recommended**. What I'm about to explain is **not recommended** either. With that out of the way...

For 1 you can install the windows DCHP service and configure it to only listen on the NIC connected to the internal network.

For 2 and 3 you can install something like [Kerio Winroute Firewall](http://www.kerio.com/products/kerio-control) and enable NAT (and transparent proxy/cache and a ton of extra functionality if you want/need it).

Again, **this is not recommended**. If you are able to get other machine (even a virtual machine) with 2 NICs you can install Kerio Firewall (or better yet something like [ipfire](http://www.ipfire.org/) or [pfsense](https://pfsense.org/) which are free) on it and use your current machine for DHCP. You can also run one of these in a virtual machine on your current pc after un-binding any protocols from the NIC connected to the external network.

In any case don't forget to un-bind any protocol (except for TCP/IP) from the NIC connected to the external network. This helps a bit with some of the issues when you multi-home a DC and it's a good security practice.

Hope this helps.